# Extending an IF statement

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress I want to call a specific secondary menu in the event a page called foo is called. I've got this beviour working by using the following:

```
<?php if (is_page('foo') ) : ?>
<!-- NAV HTML -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

However I'd like this same secondary menu to be shown on some other pages, such as foo2 which I can currently call by recycling most of the above:

```
<?php if (is_page('foo2') ) : ?>
<!-- NAV HTML -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

What would be the best way to join these statements? For instance doesnt work:

```
<?php if (is_page('foo','foo2') ) : ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wordpress docs suggest your example code:

```
<?php if (is_page('foo','foo2') ) : ?>
```

should work fine.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

However i am not particularly familiar with wordpress, so as an alternative you can use php's OR operator

```
<?php if (is_page('foo') || is_page('foo2')) : ?>
<!-- NAV HTML -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: My example code doesn't create an error and works fine for 'foo', but does not create a secondary menu for 'foo2'. Using the OR selector DOES do the trick though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [OR logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), `||`:

```
<?php if (is_page('foo') || is_page('foo2')) : ?>
    <!-- NAV HTML -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

It checks if the page is `is_page('foo')` OR `is_page('foo2')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple conditions by using &&(and) and ||(or), there are more, but these are the most used. In your case you want to use ||, so the if statement will be as followed:

```
if (is_page('foo') || is_page('foo2'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for getting the menu in both pages.

```
<?php if (is_page('foo') || is_page('foo2')) : ?>
    <!-- NAV HTML -->
<?php endif; ?>
```